# Strategy for deploying code internally and externally with common code base, but different functionality

Tags: python, version-control, deployment

For one of my current projects, written in Python, we would like to have two different versions: One for internal use, with all features enabled, and one for external use, with limited features. The current external and internal deployment method is to directly pull from git master whenever there are updates.

My initial approach to split between internal and external use, while decreasing the amount of changed code, was to implement a simple check for an existing license file. If this file exists, the code is enabling all internal features, while for a missing license file those features are silently disabled. As all features are packed into sub-modules, this approach changes the least amount of code, while I still am able to test all features for internal and external use, as I am using the same code base.

Now, this approach is no longer sufficient for my supervisor. Their argument was, as the external part always pulls the latest version from master, they will implicitly always have access to both internal and external features. By editing the code (as it is Python, that's rather straight-forward), the external users can (in theory) circumvent the internal checks, and thereby access all features, even if they are not intended for external use. Therefore, they suggest that I rather have two code bases, and port changes forth and back between both, to ensure that no part of the internal code base can leak out. Is that the only possible approach, or are there other solutions which are simpler to maintain?

Comment: That’s a matter of contracts, not software development. The external client signs a contract, and if they try to get features they didn’t pay for, you take them to court and make them pay more than for any license. Your supervisor needs to talk urgently to _his_ supervisor because he is creating a lot of unnecessary work snd therefore cost.

Answer (score 6):

"The current external and internal deployment method is to directly pull from git master"

This approach seems to have become popular with interpreted languages. But it misses an important step, the distinction between code, application and release.

A traditionally compiled application forces you to have that compilation step that separates the source code from the compiled application, but the distinction needs to be made even if you don't compile the code, It still needs testing, versioning etc

Then when you have an application, you have a separate "release" distinction, where you say, this version of my application is made available to the public under conditions X, Y and Z.

You need to implement these distinctions in your business. You cant just allow people to access your raw source code. Add a "compilation" step which takes a snapshot of your code, maybe runs a obfuscation step to make it harder to read and edit and uploads it to some separate storage.

Take this "compiled application" and test it. If it all works and you are happy, package it up into an installable zip or tar or exe, along with copywrite notices, manuals, licence agreements etc. This is your "release".

Then copy it to another separate storage location, say a website, which can then be accessed, with suitable authorisation controls, by your customers.

Comment: Related concept from [The 12-Factor App](https://12factor.net/build-release-run): “Strictly separate build and run stages. The build stage is a transform which converts a code repo into an executable bundle known as a build. The release stage takes the build produced by the build stage and combines it with the deploy’s current config.” I'd also mention that it can make sense to implement a plugin architecture to be able to select which parts of the software are shipped.